# cast float array to/from char* and send over network

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

This is how I did everything so far:

```
struct HeadPacket
{
  int type;
};

struct ReceivePacket
{
  // Header
  HeadPacket Head;
  // Raw Data
  char* buffer;
};
struct MovePacket
{
  // Header
  HeadPacket Head;
  // Raw Data
  float X;
  float Y;
};
struct ClientsPacket
{
  // Header
  HeadPacket Head;
  // Raw Data
  int Clients;
  float* X;
  float* Y;
};
```

those are some example Packets I have.

At first I create a Packet, cast it to char* and send it.

```
MovePacket m;
m.Head.type = 2;
m.X = X;
m.Y = Y;
this->Socket->Send(this->Socket->GetAddress(), (char*)&m, sizeof(m));
```

On the other side I receive it:

```
char packet[256]; //max size of a packet
SOCKADDR_IN server;
this->Socket->Receive(packet, 256, &server);
```

Now I cast it to a packet for reading the type and then I cast it further

```
    ReceivePacket* rec = (ReceivePacket*)packet;
    switch (rec->Head.type)
{
    case 0:
    {
     MovePacket* move = (MovePacket*)rec;
    }
    break;
    case 1:
    {
     ClientsPacket* c = (ClientsPacket*)rec;
    }
    break;
}
```

If I send and receive a MovePacket, everything works fine.

But if I send a ClientsPacket, which has an float array, the float array never contains the correct values.

```
    ClientsPacket c;
    c.Head.type = 3;
    c.Clients = clients.size();
    c.Y = new float[clients.size()];
    c.X = new float[clients.size()];

    int size = sizeof(c.Head) + sizeof(int)+((sizeof(float)*clients.size()) * 2);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
    {
      c.X[i] = clients[i].X;
      c.Y[i] = clients[i].Y;
      printf("X: %f Y: %f\n", c.Y[i], c.X[i]);
    }
    rc = sock.Send(newclient.GetAddr(), (char*)&c, size);
```

Do you know how to fix it and where I can read further to why it happens or can you explain to me why it happens?

Comment: Sending over the value of a pointer (essentially the address to memory in your process) to another process will not give you useful results. As a side-note your program will have problem if computers of different endianess are communicating (see `htonl` and `ntohl`)

Comment: Its getting to late, of course, really bad idea I had there. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it really should look like:
Server:

```
  ClientsPacket c;
    c.Head.type = 3;
    c.Clients = clients.size();
    c.X = new float[clients.size()];
    c.Y = new float[clients.size()];
    //define sizes
    int fsize = (sizeof(float)*clients.size());
    int hsize = sizeof(c.Head) + sizeof(c.Clients);
    int size = hsize + sizeof(float)+(fsize*2);
    //define sendchar
    char* buffer = new char[size];
    //fill arrays
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
    {
      c.X[i] = clients[i].X;
      c.Y[i] = clients[i].Y;
      printf("X: %f Y: %f\n", c.X[i], c.Y[i]);
    }
    //copy memory from client 
    memcpy(buffer, &c, hsize);
    memcpy(buffer + hsize, c.X, fsize);
    memcpy(buffer + hsize + fsize, c.Y, fsize);
```

Client:

```
ClientsReceivePacket* cv = (ClientsReceivePacket*)rec;

      ClientsPacket c;
      memcpy(&c.Head, packet, sizeof(c.Head));
      memcpy(&c.Clients, packet + sizeof(c.Head), sizeof(c.Clients));
      c.X = new float[cv->Clients];
      c.Y = new float[cv->Clients];
      //define sizes
      int hsize = sizeof(c.Head) + sizeof(c.Clients);
      int fsize = (sizeof(float)*c.Clients);
      //copy content into float array
      memcpy(c.X, packet + hsize, fsize);
      memcpy(c.Y, packet + hsize + fsize, fsize);
```